# Can $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent conditioning on $X_1+X_2$?

Tags: independence, conditional-independence

Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. I wonder if $X_1$ and $X_2$ conditioning on $X_1+X_2$ can be independent as well.

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are normally distributed, then the above statement is wrong. I wonder if the statement can be true for some random variables.

Comment: It will be helpful if you type this explicitly mathematically as a theorem.

Answer (score 6):

$X_1 ~|~ X_1+X_2$ and $X_2 ~|~ X_1+X_2$ are **not** independent. They are perfectly negatively correlated distributions.

Comment: They can be independent - see the other answers.

Comment: $X_1 + X_2$ is an instance of a "collider" for $X_1$ and $X_2$.   

This is discussed in:  [Day, Felix R., et al.](https://www.cell.com/ajhg/pdf/S0002-9297(15)00514-5.pdf)  "A robust example of collider bias in a genetic association study." The American Journal of Human Genetics 98.2 (2016): 392-393.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collider_(statistics) .

Answer (score 3):

It's possible if one of them is constant - for example if $X_1$ has a Bernoulli distribution and $X_2$ is always equal to zero.

Comment: OP: _ I wonder if the statement can be true for some random variables_

Comment: @krkeane I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Plural: "random variables", so constant ruled out.

Comment: @krkeane no, a constant random variable is still a random variable. See the "Constant random variable" section on this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution